# Fade out play/pause icon on media element - uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, mediaelement

I want to show Play/pause icon on video when it is on pause/play mode respectively. That icons should fade away after few seconds. What is the best way to apply fadeout/fadein animation to it?

```
  <MediaElement Name="videoMediaElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Stretch="Fill" PointerPressed="videoMediaElement_PointerPressed"   MediaOpened="videoMediaElement_MediaOpened" CurrentStateChanged="Media_State_Changed" >
        <MediaElement.TransportControls>
            <MediaTransportControls Background="Red" Foreground="White" IsStopButtonVisible="True" IsStopEnabled="True" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="True" IsPlaybackRateEnabled="True" IsPlaybackRateButtonVisible="True" IsFastForwardButtonVisible="True" IsFastForwardEnabled="True" IsFastRewindButtonVisible="True" IsFastRewindEnabled="True" />
        </MediaElement.TransportControls>
  </MediaElement>
  <Image x:Name="icon_play"  Source="Assets/icon_play.png" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Height="100px" Width="100"/>
  <Image x:Name="icon_pause" Source="Assets/icon_pause.png" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Height="100px" Width="100"/>

  private void Media_State_Changed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (videoMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused)
        {
            icon_play.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            icon_pause.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else if (videoMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
        {
            icon_pause.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            icon_play.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting `AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"` you have decided to use built-in media player. You can make some customization (like color), but those are very limited. If you want to build your own UI then you need to set `AreTransportControlsEnabled="False"` and create your own UI with XAML.

Comment: how can we be sure that our own xaml does everything uwp built in transport controls is doing? or do we just have to guess and try to complete as much functionality as much we can think of ? bc the built in controls are built to work on all devices with different kind of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Create XAML animation like:

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeOut" Target="icon_play" TargetProperty="Opacity">
        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

and just call `FadeOut.Begin();`

Or create (I prefer it) Composition animation:

```
        var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;

        var implicitOpacity = compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
        implicitOpacity.Target = "Opacity";
        implicitOpacity.InsertExpressionKeyFrame(1, "This.FinalValue");
        implicitOpacity.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);

        var implicitCollection = compositor.CreateImplicitAnimationCollection();
        implicitCollection["Opacity"] = implicitOpacity;

        var playVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(play_icon);
        playVisual.ImplicitAnimations = implicitCollection;
```

now each time you change value for visual's opacity - it'll be animated: `playVisual.Opacity = 0;`